Handling Angular HTTP request
This is my getRefreshToken method from service:
getRefreshToken(): Observable<AuthResponse> {
    return this.http.post<AuthResponse>(
      `${environment.WEBSITE_API_NEW_URL}/${environment.NEW_REFRESH_AUTH_TOKEN_PARAM}`,
      {},
      { observe: 'response' }
    ).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const data = response.body;
  
          this.storage.set('access_token', data.accessToken);
          this.storage.set('refresh_token', data.refreshToken);
          this.storage.set('ttl', (Date.now() + 5 * 1000).toString());
  
          return data;
        }
        throw new Error('Failed to refresh token');
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.error('Error refreshing token:', error);
        // this.logout();
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }

And this is my handleTokenExpired method in interceptor:
private handleTokenExpired(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.authService.getRefreshToken().pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        const newAccessToken: string = this.storage.get('access_token');
        const newRefreshToken: string = this.storage.get('refresh_token');

        return next.handle(this.addToken(req, newAccessToken, newRefreshToken));
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.error('Error handling expired access token:', error);
        return throwError(error);
      }),
    );
  }

In this way, HTTP request from getRefreshToken is not triggered, and when I put subscribe instead of pipe, I am getting error in handleTokenExpired that pipe does not exist on Subscription. Can somebody help?

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also, present your problem description before you show us code.

where and how do you call handleTokenExpired ?

Like this :
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const accessToken: string = this.storage.get('access_token');

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error.status === 401 && accessToken) {
          return this.handleTokenExpired(req, next);
        }

        return throwError(error);
      }),
    );
  }


In your setup with pipe, the handleTokenExpired method expects an Observable from getRefreshToken(), but since you tried using subscribe inside getRefreshToken(), it no longer returns an Observable, which leads to the error.
private handleTokenExpired(
  req: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandler,
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return this.authService.getRefreshToken().pipe(
    switchMap((authResponse) => {
      const newAccessToken: string = authResponse.accessToken;
      const newRefreshToken: string = authResponse.refreshToken;

      // Optionally store tokens in local storage
      this.storage.set('access_token', newAccessToken);
      this.storage.set('refresh_token', newRefreshToken);

      // Clone the original request with the new token
      const clonedRequest = this.addToken(req, newAccessToken, newRefreshToken);

      // Continue with the modified request
      return next.handle(clonedRequest);
    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      console.error('Error handling expired access token:', error);
      return throwError(error);
    })
  );
}


And how can I fix that? I am not sure how to do it.
